# TypeError: ActionRowBuilder is not a constructor | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
const config = require("./config.json");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Intents } = Discord;
const client = new Discord.Client({ 
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] 
})
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v10');
const { ActionRowBuilder, Events, SelectMenuBuilder } = require('discord.js'); // Problem
const commands = [
  {
    name: 'информация',
    description: 'admin info (steam64@steam!!!)'
  },
  {
    name: 'убитьбота',
    description: 'destroy bot'
  }
];
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(config.BOT_TOKEN);
(async () => {
  try {
    await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(config.CLIENT_ID), { body: commands });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (interaction.commandName === 'убитьбота') {
    interaction.reply("Успешно!");
    client.destroy();
  }
  else if (interaction.commandName === 'информация'){ // Problem
    const row = new ActionRowBuilder() // Problem
            .addComponents(
                new SelectMenuBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('select')
                    .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
                    .addOptions(
                        {
                            label: 'Select me',
                            description: 'This is a description',
                            value: 'first_option',
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'You can select me too',
                            description: 'This is also a description',
                            value: 'second_option',
                        },
                    ),
            );

        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Pong!', components: [row] });
  }
});
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Бот запущен! ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`Админов: ${config.COUNTOFADMINS}`);
  client.user.setStatus(`online`);
});
client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN)
```

The error message:

```
const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
                ^
TypeError: ActionRowBuilder is not a constructor
```

I tried to fix it but it didn't work. I was looking for a solution on the Internet, but nothing. I don't have any problem with `interactionCreate` only with selection bar on replay.

I use discord.js v13.12.0.

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` do you have?

Comment: i use 13.12.0..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `discord.js@13.12.0`, the `ActionRowBuilder` doesn't exist. It can only be used in `discord.js` v14 and above. Instead, `discord.js@13` has the `MessageActionRow`. So, in your current version, the way to create a select menu looks like this:

```js
const { MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu } = require('discord.js');
// ...
const row = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
    new MessageSelectMenu()
        .setCustomId("custom-id")
        .setPlaceholder("placeholder")
        .addOptions([
            {
                label: "Option 1",
                description: "description",
                value: "value-of-option"
            }
        ])
);
```

If you want to look at the guide for v13 code, you can go here => [discord.js v13 Guide](https://v13.discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin)